# create default html opening code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

In some html editors when you create a new html file, some default codes as below created automatically:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

how can I enable this feature in VSCode editor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press shift and 1 (!)  It will show two options select the first one or type html:5 and enter the option it will give you default boilerplate for html

Answer (score 1):

Just give the `!` sign and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image: A tutorial I found on the internet because I don't want to make one]

Answer (score 0):

In VS code( enter ctrl+n {it creates a empty text file})
then there is a link **fill with the template**  click that link it shows HTML doc type ..click that link it automatically creates a basic html file format